# Things on my JPanel are not showing up. JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am making a small game for my enjoyment and when I add my JPanel to the JFrame nothing is showing up that i have drawn in my other class.

Here is my main class

```
package Game;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import Game.Player;


public class Frame {
    static JFrame f = new JFrame("xx");
    public static JLabel points = new JLabel();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Player pl = new Player();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        points.setFont(new Font("Verdana",1,20));

        p.add(pl);
        p.add(points);


        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setSize(800, 800);
        f.setTitle("Box Game");
        f.add(p);           


        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I am having a hard time figuring it out so can someone please help me... THANKS!

Comment: I have added a `JLabel myJLabel = new JLabel("My JLabel"); p.add(myJLabel);` and it has been displayed.

Comment: This class works just fine, the label isn't diplayed because you didn't put anything in it, you probably have a problem with the player class if it was supposed to show something.

Comment: You need to create and post a [mcve] -- please read the link.

Answer (score 0):

> nothing is showing up that i have drawn in my other class.

You are add components to a panel. A JPanel uses a FlowLayout by default. The FlowLayout respects the preferred size of component you add to the panel. If the components don't paint then the preferred size of the component is probably (0, 0).

> nothing is showing up that i have drawn in my other class

If you are doing custom painting then you need to make sure you override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the class to return the size so the layout manager can do its job.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples to get you started.